# Проверка селектора на свойство CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

В файле *style.css* прописано:

```
#id1 {
    display: none;
}
```

Мой JS файл:

```
if ($('#id1').is('display', 'none')) {
    alert("YES");
}
```

Как правильно написать проверку, чтобы она срабатывала при найденном CSS свойстве?

Comment: Если же вдруг нужно просто проверять, скрыт элемент или нет, то можно воспользоваться таким условием: `if ($('#id1').is(':hidden'))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if($('#id1').css('display') == "none"){
    alert('YES');
  }
});
```

```css
#id1{
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">dawdwadawdwa</div>
```